# MVVM design choice regarding responsibility of ViewModel for simple states

Tags: wpf, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I've recently started to delve into MVVM architectural pattern. I've understood large parts of it but still few doubts remain regarding **how much responsibility ViewModel should take on behalf of View**.

In other words, **how dumb should View be**?

For example, for simple state coordination like clearing `TextView` after user presses `SubmitButton`. This kind of state coordination requires no more than one-liner to implement using some of the popular data-binding frameworks.

For example in pseudo-[ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa):

```
textView.text <~ submitButton.pressed.map { _ in "" }
```

However, Martin Fowler wrote in his [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html),

> The Presentation Model contains the logic that says that the composer field is only enabled if the check box is checked, so the when the view updates itself from the Presentation Model, the composer field control changes its enablement state

which suggests that even the simple logic like clearing out `TextView` after pressing `Button` should be encapsulated inside `ViewModel`.

Such design choice leads to something like this (again, in pseudo-ReactiveCocoa):

```
// In View
viewModel.submitButtonPressed <~ submitButton.pressed
textView.text <~ viewModel.textViewText

// In ViewModel
textViewText <~ viewModel.submitButtonPressed.map { _ in "" }
```

Although it leads to better encapsulation of logics while assuming view with the job of binding only (making it dumb), it does make code a lot more verbose and lead to tighter coupling between `View` and `ViewModel` (by requiring `ViewModel` to be aware of `SubmitButton`).

I'm still new to MVVM pattern in general and learning stuff every day.

**How much responsibility should ViewModel take?**

In other words, must `View` be completely dumb and only handle simple binding (connect its UI elements to bindable property provided by `ViewModel`) or is it okay for `View` to handle fairly simple logic like the above?

On a side note, is tight coupling between `View` and `ViewModel` **okay** in MVVM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the `ViewModel` takes all responsibility. More specifically, in your scenario, the `ViewModel` wouldn't know about the `submitButton`, but rather the `View` would know that the `ViewModel` exposes a command (an `ICommand`) called `SubmitCommand`, and have the `submitButton` bind to that command.

Sometimes it can get a bit more involved to completely separate the actions and corresponding logic, for instance when there's no binding available for a command for a specific event. But in those cases a fairly simple attached behavior (i.e. `InvokeCommandAction` and friends, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity(v=expression.40).aspx)) can bridge that gap to coax flow so the logic can go in to the `ViewModel`.

Very rarely, there are scenarios (of which none come to mind currently) where it gets *so* involved that I just skip the whole idea, and separate as much as possible, rather than to have to work out three months later *exactly* what the hell is going on. But those cases are rare indeed.

Comment: Small correction: It takes all **presentation logic**. View related logic and business logic don't belong there though. It's important to mention, since many beginners to MVVM start putting business logic into their ViewModel

Comment: Right. But then wouldn't `ViewModel` still need to know about `TextView` to update its `textViewText` property inside `SubmitCommand` (Although, I'm not too familiar with `ICommand` since I don't have background in wpf)?

Comment: Nope, since TextView.Text would also be bound to property of the ViewModel, and would update it accordingly if the ViewModel's property would change. I don't how familiar you are with WPF, but perhaps [the databinding section of the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx) might give you more insight.

Comment: @Tseng: True indeed. I'll try to find a proper way of phrasing it without making it more confusing, if I have time.

Comment: @DanielShin: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms750612(v=vs.100).aspx) might be a better place to look. The contents of the previous link I posted don't do a good job of explaining it IMO.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Thanks I'll take a look!

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, must View be completely dumb and only handle simple binding

It's quite good, when view contains data bindings only, but IRL complex views can contain some view-specific logic. E.g., since single view model could be connected to a several views, focus management is a view's prerogative. Another sample is a logic like "hide element A if element B is disabled", or "change color from A to B if button is checked", etc.

XAML frameworks provide several techniques to make view logic more well-composed: commands, triggers, attached behaviors, value converters. But sometimes you actually need code-behind.

> For example, for simple state coordination like clearing TextView
>   after user presses SubmitButton

To be more clear. *This is not* a view logic, and must be placed in view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private string someText;

    public string SomeText 
    { 
        get { return someText; }
        set
        {
            if (someText != value)
            {
                someText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        } 
    }

    private ICommand submitCommand;

    public ICommand SumbitCommand
    {
        if (submitCommand == null)
        {
            submitCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                // do submit
                // clear text
                SomeProperty = null;
            });
        }
        return submitCommand;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SomeTextBox" Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
<Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}">
```

But *this is* a view logic:

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // SomeTextBox should have initial focus
    Loaded += (sender, args) => SomeTextBox.Focus();
}
```

> is tight coupling between View and ViewModel okay in MVVM?

Ideally all components should be loosely coupled, but view *must* know about view model properties to perform data binding.